# Поменять стиль для балуна Яндекса в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты

Как поменять стиль балуна Яндекса в React.js?

Для preset "islands#blueStretchyIcon" нужно убрать обводку и сделать тень под балуном. Как это сделать и где? Конечно, [есть документация](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/) и [песочница](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/icon_customImage/)   Однако эксперименты ни к чему не привели.

Кусок кода в react, который отвечает за добавление placemark

```
changeActivePlacemark: function(newPlacemarkId){
    this.ymapsPlacemarks && this.ymapsPlacemarks.each((placemark)=>{
        if(placemark.properties.get('id') == newPlacemarkId){
            placemark.options.set('preset', 'twirl#violetStretchyIcon');
            placemark.options.set('zIndex', 2);
        } else {
            placemark.options.set('preset', 'twirl#blueStretchyIcon');
            placemark.options.set('zIndex', 1);
        }
    })
},

deleteSelectedObject: function(){
    this.deleteObject(this._selectedAreaIndex);
},

deleteObject: function(index){
    console.log('delete');

    if(this.__radiusTool){
        this.__radiusTool.finishEdit()
        this.__radiusTool = null;
    }

    this.deselectArea();

    this.ymapsAreas.remove(this.ymapsAreas.get(index));
    // Добавляет курсор на карту
    this.areaMap.cursors.push('grab');
    this.handleObjectsChange(this.getData());
},

deleteAllObjects: function(){
    this.ymapsAreas.each(this.deleteObject, this);
},

addPlacemark: function(placemark){
    // Устанавливает содержимое балуна    

    var preset = 'islands#blueStretchyIcon';

    if(this.props.activePlacemark == placemark.id){
        preset = 'islands#violetStretchyIcon';
    }
    var addRandom = this.props.addRandom;

    var pointGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",// тип геометрии - точка
            coordinates: [
                Number(placemark.lon) + (addRandom?Math.random()/10000:0),
                Number(placemark.lat) + (addRandom?Math.random()/10000:0)
            ], // координаты точки
            name: placemark.name,
            description: placemark.description
        },
        properties: {
            id: placemark.id,
            iconContent: placemark.iconContent,
            hintContent: placemark.hintContent,
            balloonContent: placemark.balloonContent,
            balloonContentHeader: placemark.balloonContentHeader,
            balloonContentBody: placemark.balloonContentBody,
            balloonContentFooter: placemark.balloonContentFooter
        }
    },{
        preset,
        draggable: placemark.isDraggable
    });
```

Comment: Я ответил и понял что ответил не та тот вопрос. Вам нужно именно балун стилизовать или саму метку (просто ИМХО она тоже на балун похожа)?

Comment: Если можно, покажите картинку, которую вы хотите получить

Answer (score 1):

Стили `islands#****StretchyIcon` отрисовываются картинкой (background-image). Именно поэтому у них нельзя задавать любой цвет (чтобы убрать обводку в версии 2.1, придется менять SVG, который встроен в стилях меток, в версии 2.0 пришлось бы перерисовывать растр и менять фон).

Для вашего случая видимо нужно разрабатывать свой Layout. Правда тень можно все-таки "настилить" в css примерно так:

```
.ymaps-2-1-29-placemark-overlay {
    /* 2-1-29 - это только для текущей версии. Поменяется версия, поменяется и класс */
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 2px #999);
            filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 2px #999);
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ. Мне наверное, нужно поменять метку. Нужно, чтобы она была как здесь  https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/option.presetStorage-docpage/  в разделе  "Placemarks with text (icons stretch to fit the content)" - 'islands#grayStretchyIcon', только без серой обводки и на тени. Скажите, пожалуйста, а где можно поподробнее узнать, как создавать свой Layout или перерисовывать этот svg. Как это сделать в реакте?